# Generic Views using Prism and Modularity

Tags: wpf, prism

I am trying to implement prism in an application. I defined regions in Shell.xaml and called Views of Modules in different regions.
I don't know if Prism allows or not the generic views: i have a lot of views very similar but changing the bidings and the labels names, can i generate these views using modularity and divide a module view in Regions like for the shell.xaml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can devide a view that belongs to a module into several regions. Regions do not have to be in the outer Window or view.